# Running batch file containing NuGet commands from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, shell, nuget

I have a batch file containing the following commands:

```
cd C:\myfolder
NuGet Update -self
NuGet pack mypackage.nuspec
```

myfolder contains mypackage.nuspec and NuGet.exe. I try to run this command with C# using the following function:

```
        private static int ExecuteCommand(string path)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
            Process Process;

            ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
            ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            ProcessInfo.WorkingDirectory = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).DirectoryName;
            ProcessInfo.EnvironmentVariables["EnableNuGetPackageRestore"] = "true";


            // *** Redirect the output ***
            ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;


            Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
            Process.WaitForExit();

            // *** Read the streams ***
            string output = Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            int ExitCode = Process.ExitCode;
            Process.Close();
            return ExitCode;

        }
```

However, my commands are not executed. What is causing this behavior and what is the solution? Those strings will probably be used in the future, I'll update my question then (just to prevent chriticism :)).

This is the final version of the function:

```
    private static ShellCommandReturn ExecuteCommand(string path)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
        Process process;

        processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).DirectoryName;
        processInfo.EnvironmentVariables["EnableNuGetPackageRestore"] = "true";


        // *** Redirect the output ***
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;


        process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();

        // *** Read the streams ***
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
        process.Close();
        return new ShellCommandReturn { Error = error, ExitCode = exitCode, Output = output };
    }
```

ShellCommandReturn is a simple custom class with a few data members where error, output and exit code of a shell command are stored.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: After a certain amount of collaboration :)

The problem is that this is executing in the context of a web application, which doesn't have the same environment variables set.

Apparently setting:

```
startInfo.EnvironmentVariables["EnableNuGetPackageRestore"] = "true"
```

(using the naming of my final code below) fixes the problem.

---

**Old answer** (still worth reading)

Look at this code:

```
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
ProcessInfo.WorkingDirectory = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).DirectoryName;

Process = Process.Start(path);
```

You're creating a `ProcessStartInfo`, but then completely ignoring it. You should be passing it into `Process.Start`. You should also rename your variables. Conventionally local variables start with lower case in C#. Additionally, it's a good idea to initialize variables at the point of first use, where possible. Oh, and import namespaces so you don't fully qualified names such as `System.IO.FileInfo` in your code. Finally, object initializers are useful for classes like `ProcessStartInfo`:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path) {
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    UseShellExecute = true,
    WorkingDirectory = new FileInfo(path).DirectoryName;
};
var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks for the constructive critisism, but do you know a solution to the problem?

Comment: @LajosArpad: Well have you tried the changed code? I expect it will work - you need the information you've put into your `ProcessStartInfo`, but you're ignoring it, so you won't end up with that when you just call `Process.Start(path)`. That *is* the solution to the problem - I just gave you a bunch of code hygiene tips as well.

Comment: No, it doesn't execute the NuGet commands. I've edited my question with the new C# code.

Comment: @LajosArpad: So what *does* happen? Do you see any errors? Perhaps it's a path issue for nuget? (What happens if you fully-qualify that in the batch file?) If you add diagnostics to the batch file, e.g. writing some message out to disk, does *that* get run?

Comment: I don't see any errors and the path is correct. Yes, I have tested the path. I suppose a setting might be missing, but I don't know really the reason of this behavior.

Comment: @LajosArpad: And have you tested whether the batch file is being executed at all? (Why are you setting the working directory if you're then changing directory at the start of the batch file...)

Comment: The batch script copied folders and files in my tests. It is running.

Comment: @LajosArpad: So it's *just* nuget which is failing, and you've tried giving the complete path to nuget.exe within the batch file?

Comment: Exactly. I don't know what is the issue running nuget commands from C#, as running the batch file directly from cmd works impeccably.

Comment: @LajosArpad: I've just noticed the asp.net tag - are you trying to do this from within a web application? If so, it sounds like it's a permissions issue. Try doing it from a console app first, and check *that* works.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying from a web application after the console tests were successful. My problem was that ProcessInfo.EnvironmentVariables["EnableNuGetPackageRestore"] = "true"; was not set. If you add this to your answer I will gladly accept it and upvote it, thanks for trying hard. In the meantime I will Edit my question and will put the working C# code into it to help programmers encountering this issue in the future.

Comment: @LajosArpad: Done - let me know if that doesn't capture everything correctly.

Comment: It does, thank you, I will finalize my question to make it more helpful, but your answer is already very nice.